# Generating Excel file based on folder contents

Tags: excel

Is it possible to create a excel spreadsheet based on a folder tree, including its subdirectories and filenames? Is their a way to do it with excel itself or is there a program out there that makes this possible?

Comment: I'm not aware of any program that will create this for you but it should be fairly straight forward to write in a number of different programming languages. I would recommend you investigate with one that you are most familiar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know there is many ways to go about doing this, but the simplest method that worked for me was this, not exactly autogenerating to an excel file but it accomplished what I needed:

http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/443101.html

Thanks for the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this just once and not update it, then something like this should work:

```
 cd directory
 tree > tree.txt
```

Now do following:

1. Open `tree.txt` in a text editor which can do regular expressions, such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). The regular expressions below are for Notepad++, so you may have to tweak them a bit for another editor with different regexp dialect. Notice how each directory tree level is 4 prefixing characters.
2. Remove any lines you don't care about.
3. Replace, with regular expression and wrap-around checkboxes checked:

   - Find: `^(\t*)[^\tA-Za-z0-9_]{4}`
   - Replace: `\1\t`
4. Keep repeating above step until 0 occurences are replaced. Look at how file changes.
5. Copy the text (*ctrl-a ctrl-c*) and paste to Excel. Tab characters should put directory hierarchy neatly to Excel columns

---

Some notes about the regexp:

- `\t` is Tab character, both in expression and replacement
- `\1` in replacement means whatever whas matched by first `()` in the expression
- Initial `^` in expression matches start of line
- `[^`...`]` in expression means, match any character *not* listed
- `{4}` in expression means, match exactly 4 occurences of whatever was before (the `[^`...`]` in this case).

So in short, this matches and `()`-captures any tabs at start of line, then matches also next 4 non-tab/letter/number/underscore chars. Then this is replaced first by any tabs that were captured, then one extra tab. So each time this regexp is done, one more sequence of 4 non-directory-name chars get replaced with tab.

Answer (score 0):

One solution approach is using Java with Apache POI, see http://poi.apache.org/. You can read the directory structure in Java. Depending on which element, you can create a excel spredsheet. See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html for further documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily done in VBA with a or two self referring Sub where you use Dir commands with Loops, with this Sub you can go UP and DOWN the tree based on the two parameters transferred:

1. The Directory path
2. The direction (up or down)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this Excel file:

http://www.formedia.ca/files/arborescence_(v0097).xlsm

(arborescence means treeview in French)

Simply place it in the root of the tree you want to capture and click the "Read tree" button.

There are many undocumented feature, like creating a new dated file and the maximum number of levels, exclusion list, ... Check the different tabs in the user form and jump back here if you have any question (like reading French :).

You can always modify the VBA code to suit your particular requirements.

Hope this helps...